# what is the meaning of templates which are used inside triple curly braces in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8

what is the meaning of templates which are used inside triple curly braces in Laravel 8?

{{{ $errors->first('xxxx', ':message') }}}

im not getting what is this?

Answer (score 0):

Difference between the double and triple curly braces is that the triple curly braces runs the value through the e() helper function, which is just a shortcut to the PHP htmlentities function.

```
{{ "Unfiltered input: ".$data['name'] }}
{{{ "Filtered input: ".$data['name'] }}}
```

compiled

```
<?php echo "Unfiltered input: ".$data['name']; ?>
<?php echo e("Filtered input: ".$data['name']); ?>
```

Comment: e() helper function?